# Converting String to Character to Integer

Tags: indexing, integer, character, decimal

I am trying to take a string (@"12345") and extractor each individual character and convert to it's decimal equivalent.

@"1" = 1
@"2" = 2
etc.

Here is what I have this far:

```
...
[self ArrayOrder:@"1234"];
...

-(void)ArrayOrder(Nsstring *)Directions
 {



   NSString *singleDirections = [[NSString alloc] init];

   //Loop Starts Here

   *singleDirection = [[Directions characterAtIndex:x] intValue];

   //Loop ends here


 }
```

I have been receiving type errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `[Directions characterAtIndex:x]` returns a `unichar`, which is a Unicode character.

Instead, you can use NSRange and substrings to get each number out of the string:

```
NSRange range;
range.length = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < Directions.length; i++) {
    range.location = i;
    NSString *s = [Directions substringWithRange:range];
    int value = [s integerValue];
    NSLog(@"value = %d", value);
}
```

Another approach would be to use `/ 10` and `% 10` to get to each number from the string individually. Such as:

```
NSString* Directions = @"1234";
int value = [Directions intValue];
int single = 0;
while(value > 0) {
    single = value % 10;
    NSLog(@"value is %d", single);
    value /= 10;
}
```

However, that goes through your string backwards.